# Is it possible to write a vector form ODE to an explicit form?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, vector-fields

Any explicit differential equation of order n,
$F\left(x,y,y',y'',\ \ldots ,\ y^{(n-1)}\right)=y^{(n)}$
can be written as a system of n first-order differential equations.

Conversely, can any vector form be rewritten into an explicit form?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is not.

- With a explicit form always we can re-write it as a implicit form.
- With a implicit form not always we can re-write it as a explicit form.

An example for the second case is a Clairaut ordinary differential equation $$y=xy'+(y')^{2}$$
Also, you can find more example in [implicit differential equation](https://www.efunda.com/math/ode/ode1_implicit.cfm).

Comment: Can you give a simple example?

Comment: Of course,  suppose we have the ODE: $\frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}x}=\frac{-e^{y}}{2y+xe^{y}}$ has general solution in implicit form as $xe^{y}+y^{2}=C$. Now, try to find $y(x)$ (explicit form).

Comment: Similar case for the ODE in itself. The implicit form is given by $F(x,y,y')=0$ for example and *if* the equation can be solved for $y'$ so we have the explicit form $y'=f(x,y)$. These terms are directly associated with the possibility of solving the equation in terms of other variables.

Comment: That ODE is already in explicit form. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation#General_definition

Comment: @Moyapon I have updated my answer following the idea of your requirement. If you agree, you can click the accept answer button. Please let me know if there is any further question.